# Monit Httpd interface not working

Tags: monit

I am trying to use httpd interface to view monit results in web browser.
I have used the below commands in my monitrc file.

```
set httpd port 2812 
allow monit:monit
```

But when i try to log into web browser with http://localhost:2812/
The page fails with page not found error.

I have ensured that there is no firewall restriction for localhost:2812 port and also from the local host, the port is listening for monit.

```
$netstat -nlpt |grep 2812
```

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2812                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      42291/monit

I dont even get any failure logs under monit.log

Appreciate your help on this concern.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to access from "localhost", you need also the following line:

```
set httpd port 2812
allow localhost # <-----
allow monit:monit
```

Regards

Reference: https://www.mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#MONIT-HTTPD